# Excel, list all dates with a value

Tags: arrays, excel

I am working on an invoicing system using Excel.
I have a list of dates and customers.
Each date a service is required, a number indicating the number of hours is entered, essentially a job sheet.
I want the invoice to show a list of dates where the customer has booked.
I did this in Google sheets, and by it worked:

```
=arrayformula(concatenate(if(not(ISBLANK(B2:D2)),text(B1:D1,"dd/MM/yyyy")&", ","")))
```

I have now spent weeks trying to get excel to do something similar, but have come up blank.
Anyone have any idea how to do this in Excel?
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to generate (an example would help), so I don't know if you really need an array formula. But since that's what you're using here and it works, note that Excel does them differently. Google search on "excel array formula" (you need to press "Ctrl-Shift-Enter" to create one).

Comment: Also, unless you have Excel 2016, you won't be able to concatenate multiple strings derived from an array as you appear to be able to do so in Google Sheets.

Comment: A csv list in one cell like: "12/09/2016, 20/09/2016, 25/09/2016".
I am using Excel 2016 if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Excel 2016, I believe you can use:

`=CONCAT(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:D2)),TEXT(B1:D1,"dd/MM/yyyy")&", ",""))`

entered as an **array formula****.

Unfortunately I don't have that version so am unable to verify this.

I should also add that `TEXTJOIN` may be a minimally more efficient choice here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still get #NAME? Error though.

Comment: But you're attempting this using Excel 2016, no?

Comment: Ah, there appear to be some additional conditions for the use of some of these 2016 functions: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCAT-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2: Quote: "IMPORTANT: This function is available if: 1) You are an Office 365 subscriber and have the latest version of Office installed on your PC; 2) You are using Excel Online; 3) You are using Excel Mobile; 4) You are using Excel for Android phones and tablets"

Comment: Oh, any other way then?

Comment: Is the range in question fixed at just 4 cells? Or does any solution need to be extendable to work for larger ranges? If the latter, VBA will be required - is this an option for you?

Comment: It is quite a lot of cells, usually about 2 months worth. Happy to give it a go on the VBA front. It has been a long time since I used it though.

Answer (score 0):

For pre-2016:

```
Sub Concat_Vals()

Dim r       As Range
Dim Result  As String

For Each r In Range("A1:D1")
    If Len(r.Offset(1, 0)) > 0 Then
        Result = Result & ", " & r
    End If
Next r

Result = Mid(Result, 3)
Range("A10").Value = Result

End Sub
```

which returns the concatenated result into cell `A10` and operates over the range `A1:D1` (change both as required in the above).

Or, as a UDF:

```
Function Concat_Vals(Rng As Range)

For Each r In Rng
    If Len(r) > 0 Then
        Result = Result & ", " & Cells(1, r.Column)
    End If
Next r

Concat_Vals = Mid(Result, 3)

End Function
```

Regards

Comment: Hi, I tried this as a function, but I just get a Value error. It didnt work at all in the Sub.

Comment: Worked fine for me as a Sub. Can you elaborate on "didn't work at all"?

Comment: It did nothing. As far as I could tell. I think, as it needs to be applied to multiple rows, it would need to be a function anyway wouldn't it?

Comment: I didn't explicitly include a sheet name, so I take it you ran the Sub whilst the active sheet was the relevant one? And also that the ranges I used were amended accordingly? Note that row 2 is not explicitly referenced, but rather implicitly as a row offset from the range ("A1:D1") specified. It wouldn't need to be a function - I could add a simple loop to cover multiple rows - though obviously it would help if you could first get it to work for a single row.

Comment: Going back to your original solution, I have a test file with A1:D1 with data, added a new module by double clicking the active sheet. I pasted the sub in there, and saved the file. Nothing then happens. As I said, I used to use VB all the time about 15 years ago, but cant really remember much now, so I am happy to accept that I may be just doing it all wrong!

Comment: OK, you have to run it! So this gives me a csv list with even blank cells, and doesn't return the dates from the first row? Can it be done as function? This way when a new customer is added, the cell could just be copied down.

Comment: Please tell me what result the code gives using some random values in A1:D2, and let me also know those values.

Comment: It does work! How do I do this on multiple rows, not knowing the count of rows on the fly?

Comment: So you'd prefer a UDF rather than the current sub extended to work for any number of rows?

Comment: Yes, I think a Function would be more future proof. as it could include extra date cols and customer rows fairly automatically. I tried to adapt what you wrote to a function, using a negative Offset (to find the date row, although it is always in row 1, so I may be over-thinking) , but not even sure if the range can be passed to the function in the way that I am trying to do it. I got as far as the oh so helpful #VALUE! error.

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: XOR LX, you are a genius! Thank you so much. I used the function the end.